# Get active window without global hooks or polling GetActiveWindow?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

How can I get notifications about what is the currect active window and when this changes without polling GetActiveWindow or using global hooks?

I don't like polling, and I'm working in C# and global hooks don't work (mostly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never found a clean way to get notified. I use [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505.aspx) with a timer. :(

Comment: I know this post is really old but I'm just dropping a comment to a similar post that arrived at a different conclusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407631/is-there-windows-system-event-on-active-window-changed

Answer (score 0):

You can't but you might want to try something someone has already created like this [product](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/Vb/Code/Libraries/Hooks/vbAccelerator_Hook_Library/article.asp).