# Determine when a third-party application becomes active

Tags: c#, windows

Is there a way I can detect when a certain third party application running on the system (e.g. thunderbird.exe) becomes the active?

Alternatively, out of all the processes running on the system, is it possible to get the name of the currently active process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407631/is-there-windows-system-event-on-active-window-changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks spender for the links. I've been able to use the information in those questions to create a reusable component that returns a Process object for the active window and triggers an event when it changes.

The code for this is available here: https://github.com/DanStevens/ActiveWindowWatcher/blob/master/ActiveWindowWatcher.cs