# How to record screentime in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am a newbie to C++ and wanted to create a Screentime application like in ios for windows. But unfortunately, I am stuck after creating the default bootstrap by using visual studio 2019. Can anyone suggest to me what I should do next and other related resources?
I just wanted to create a simple app (let's say screentime) that monitors other apps active and focused state whenever the screentime app is run and store the app name, start time and end time in a text file.

Comment: **Programming Windows** by Charles Petzold has been the *go to* book for learning Windows programming for many Windows developers.  It'll tremendously help you get underway.

Comment: @Eljay agree that it's a well done book but there's nothing on `setwindowshookex()` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Windows APIs should help with this:

1. [`GetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) will return the window the user is currently working in.
2. [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) will retrieve the process ID corresponding to that window.
3. There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885687/5743288) which shows how to map the process ID to a process name.

It's then a matter of doing this periodically on a timer to keep track of the current application and logging the results.

---

As noted in the comments, there is a better way to track when the foreground window changes.  You can use [`SetWinEventHook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) to install a handler to listen for such changes and then take the desired action in your handler when it does.

You would call `SetWinEventHook` like this:

```
HWINEVENTHOOK hHook = SetWinEventHook (EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
    NULL, MyEventHandler, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
```

Where [`MyEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-wineventproc) would be declared like this:

```
void CALLBACK MyEventHandler (
  HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook,
  DWORD event,
  HWND hwnd,
  LONG idObject,
  LONG idChild,
  DWORD idEventThread,
  DWORD dwmsEventTime
)
{ ... }
```

And `hwnd` is passed as the new foreground window.

Finally, pass `hHook` to [`UnhookWinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unhookwinevent) before exiting your application (or when the hook is no longer needed).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618720/is-there-any-system-event-which-fires-when-getforegroundwindow-changes   How i said early haha

Comment: [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) is the correct way to do this. No need to periodically ask *"Are we there yet?"*. Just have the system set an alarm for you, and you won't sleep right through the interesting parts.